# Create a notfication window from taskbar

Tags: swing

When My application starting, I ask for a passcode.I would like to prmpt it as a notification from the taskbar(a small baloon shaped) like [blootooth-compuer pairing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu should lookup classes

```
SystemTray
```

and

```
TrayIcon
```

especially

```
TrayIcon.displayMessage
```